# Delay of 10mn between resource creation with Terraform Vsphere provider

Tags: delay, terraform, vsphere

Is there a way to delay module resource creation with the Terraform Vsphere provider. I want to introduce a 10mn delay due to infrastructure impediments between each VM instance creation. Each one is created by a module occurrence.

At the moment, Terraform is doing its best to deploy at maximum speed!

I tried `depends_on` with module: no way.

Versions used:

```
vsphere 6.0
terraform 0.11.3
provider.vsphere v 1.3.2
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a provisioner within the instance and have some kind of sleep command there, before the next VM instance is created.

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vpshere_build_machine" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = "ping 127.0.0.1 -n 10 > nul" #or sleep 10
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I found another solution bu terraform cli option with terraform -parallelism=1 apply and with TF_CLI_ARGS env variable. It s not 10mn delay but provisionning of instance respect the duration. Regards

Answer (score 0):

In my case I could solve it by doing this trick:

```
"sleep [s] && command"
```

For example:

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "sleep 30 && ansible-playbook -i ..."
  }
```